# Как измеряется размер чего либо в платформе андроид

Tags: android

android:textSize="30" что должно стоять после "30"

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/11-pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density.html

Comment: dp не срабатывает

Comment: sp нужно писать, по ссылке про это тоже упомянули

Comment: Спасибо огромное